# CLion custom compiler: Makefile parser says "No compilation commands found"

Tags: macos, makefile, clion, retro-computing

I'm trying to get a custom compiler working in CLion and having a bear of a time. Can anyone help me find out what I'm doing wrong? I have the [full code on Github](https://github.com/uliwitness/mpw-sillyballs).

#### What I have

- The command line tools are all behind the same executable named `mpw`. So the C compiler is behind `mpw SC`, the linker is behind `mpw link`. There's also a tool named `Rez` to add some metadata to the executable, but I'm fine if CLion just ignores that.
- I'm using a [make file](https://github.com/uliwitness/mpw-sillyballs/blob/main/Makefile) to do the actual build.
- I've created a [custom compiler definition YAML](https://github.com/uliwitness/mpw-sillyballs/blob/main/clion-custom-compiler-mpw-ppc.yaml) and selected it in CLion's project settings. I tried to follow the Jetbrains docs [[1]](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/custom-compilers.html) [[2]](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/settings-languages-cpp-clangd.html) but couldn't find out what code insight target name to use (It eventually compiles for 68000 CPU, old MacOS, anyone know where I can find a list of allowed `clangd` target names?).
- The Makefile works when I call `make clean` or `make all` from command line.

#### Problem

When I open the folder in CLion, it tries to parse the Makefile and reports:

```
(x) Analysing makefile
(x) No compilation commands found
```

#### Goal

- Get CLion to see all my code (including system headers at `~/mpw/Interfaces/CIncludes`) so I can use its code navigation to auto-complete code. Refactoring would be nice too.
- Get CLion to understand my Makefile so I can build using the "hammer" icon inside CLion.

#### Custom Compiler Definition

```yaml
compilers:
  - description: "MPW SC"
    match-sources: ".*\\.c"
    match-language: "C"
    match-compiler-exe: "(.*/)?mpw SC"
    code-insight-target-name: mpw
    include-dirs:
      - ${user-home}/mpw/Interfaces/CIncludes
    defines-text: "
#define __MRC__ 0x0700
#define OLDROUTINENAMES 1
"
```

#### Makefile

```
SOURCES=SillyBalls.c
RFILES=SillyBalls.r Size.r
EXECUTABLE=SillyBalls

MPW=~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw
RINCLUDES=~/mpw/Interfaces/RIncludes

LDFLAGS =-w -c 'SILB' -t APPL \
    -sn STDIO=Main -sn INTENV=Main -sn %A5Init=Main

LIBRARIES={Libraries}Stubs.o \
    {Libraries}MacRuntime.o \
    {Libraries}IntEnv.o \
    {Libraries}Interface.o \
    {Libraries}ToolLibs.o \
    {CLibraries}StdCLib.o

TOOLBOXFLAGS=-d OLDROUTINENAMES=1 -typecheck relaxed

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.c=obj/%.o)

all: prepass bin/$(EXECUTABLE)

prepass:
    mkdir -p obj bin

bin/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(MPW) link $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES) -o $@
    Rez -rd $(RFILES) -o $@ -i $(RINCLUDES) -append

obj/%.o : %.c
    $(MPW) SC $(TOOLBOXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf bin obj
```

Comment: What's all that `{Libraries}` and `{CLibraries}` stuff?  Do you really have files with those literal names?  You don't appear to be building those, so do those names have special meaning to `mpw`, or something?

Comment: It may be that CLion is not smart enough to recognize that the expansion of (say) `$(MPW) SC` matches your C compiler pattern.  You could try instead defining and using `CC = ~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw SC`, *etc*..

Comment: Yeah, `{Libraries}` etc. are standard symbols for some standard folders the compiler knows how to find.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be part of the problem: I added `CC="~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw SC"` and  `LD="~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw link"` it seems more happy, though it of course now says `Cannot find compiler executable: '~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw SC'` which is true. Maybe I can create a bash script that forwards to these two sub-commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnBollinger for getting me on the right track:

CLion is apparently not smart enough to recognize `$(MPW) SC` as `mpw SC`. If I change it to

```
CC="~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw SC"
```

CLion is happy, but of course there is no file named `mpw SC`.

So my solution was to create a shell script `sc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

~/Programming/mpw/build/bin/mpw SC $@
```

and then set

```
CC=./sc.sh
```

and

```yaml
  match-compiler-exe: "(.*/)?sc.sh"
```

and then use `./sc.sh` everywhere where I used to have `$(MPW) SC`

CLion recognizes it, starts indexing the system headers, and the "hammer" icon triggers a `build all` just as desired.

Comment: Or you could just lose the quotes in your variable definitions.  They are neither necessary for nor meaningful to `make`, but when `make` carries them forward to the shell, the problem you describe arises.  It was not accidental that I omitted quotes from my suggestion in comments on the question.

Comment: You're right, if I do a binary directory path instead of the path *including* the mpw tool, it will be recognized even if it's a separate variable. Updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: Dangit, I just realized it does _not_ work. It must have cached something making it seem like that worked. The script is necessary after all.